# Simple web server example - why do I have to put the property name in quotes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following example:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead({
    'content-type': 'text/plain'
  });
  response.end('Hello world!');
});

server.listen(8000);
```

Why do I have to put the `content-type` property name into quotes? Isn't writeHead expecting a plain JS object? Why can't I write something like:

```
{
  content-type: 'text/plain'
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must quote the property name of a JavaScript object literal if the name is not a [valid identifier](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch02_07.htm) (i.e. something you could use as a variable name); integers are apparently ok too.  Since the dash character (`-`) is not a valid part of an identifier you must quote the string.

```javascript
var o;
o = {content-type: 'text/plain'}; // => SyntaxError: Unexpected token "-"
o = {'content-type': 'text/plain'}; // => OK
o = {contentType: 'text/plain'}; // => OK
o = {123: 456}; // => OK
o = {$x: 123}; // => OK
o = {π: 234}; // => OK
```